# Android Change Widget Background Image

Tags: android, background, bitmap, widget, drawable

Been struggling for the past two days to change the background of my widget, based on some if statements (removed right now just want to change the widget background from the class) here is my source below. What's up though, I've changed images before fine such as backgrounds but can not get it to work for my widget thank you. This is my most recent attempt by the way

```
//Widget Provider Class
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.widget.WidgetDialog.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget, ((BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.widget_background)).getBitmap());

        }
    }
}



//Widget Layout XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried the same and never found a solution, it seems as if you can not change the background of a widget after the layout-inflation. This might be due to RemoteView-Limitations.
I wanted a solid-widget (alpha=255) and a semi-transparent one (alpha=128). As a solution I created two layouts with the corresponding layouts and switched the alyouts when I wanted to switch backgrounds.

Comment: exactly what i ended up doing unfortunately meant i had to add 10 different xmls in since i just wanted to change 5 different images based on different ifs so needed 10 seems pretty inefficient but what can you do i hear ice cream sandwich will give us better widget control though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone got any other ideas? Really would like to get this figured out

Edit: ended up setting up different layouts currently have 10 different layouts for 2 different widgets inefficient but working more of a hack around really

Answer (score 17):

Here's a trick that you can do: use ImageView for you background, not "background" property of you View and set scaleType to "fitXY". Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/some_background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">       

        <Button
            android:text="some button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- all your views -->

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now you can switch your ImageView source during runtime:

```
//updating current widget
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

views.setImageViewResource(R.id.backgroundImage, R.drawable.some_other_background);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
```

Comment: @Vladimir Sizov How to load image from url?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `setImageViewResource()`

```
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget, R.drawable.widget_background);
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this in the past as its what made the most sense to me but writing what u suggest errors should be views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget, R.drawable.widget_background) ; which then also doesn't work so in the xml I set the background to #00000000 but then what I set in my class doesn't show I just have a clear widget any other suggestions? Thanks