# Widget ImageView not updating

Tags: android

I am trying to make a clock widget in which I have a ImageView with custom font.

Here is the code by which I am updating the widget in 1 sec interval.

[code]

```
package com.coderzheaven.customfontinwidget;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyTimer extends TimerTask {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    static Context thisContext;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    ComponentName thisWidget;
    Handler mHandler;

    public MyTimer(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        MyTimer.thisContext = context;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(thisContext.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_main);

        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        System.out.println("TIMER STARTED................");

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {

        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (final int appWidgetId : allWidgetIds) {

            if (mHandler != null) {

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        System.out.println("UPDATING......" + getTodaysTime() + " ID = " + appWidgetId);

                        Bitmap bmp = buildUpdate(getTodaysTime());

                        setBitmap(remoteViews, R.id.imageView_txt, bmp);

                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,
                                remoteViews); 

                    }
                }

                );

            }

        }

    } 



    public static Bitmap buildUpdate(String time) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 250, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(thisContext.getAssets(),
                "digital-7.ttf");
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
        paint.setTypeface(clock);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(60);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        myCanvas.drawText(time, 120, 60, paint);
        return myBitmap;
    }

    private void setBitmap(RemoteViews views, int resId, Bitmap bitmap){
        Bitmap proxy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(proxy);
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(resId, proxy);
    }

    public static String getTodaysTime() {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        return new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)).append(":").append(pad(seconds)).toString();
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
}
```

[/code]

But my problem is the the time is updated only once.
I can't find a solution.

This is my AppWidgetProviderClass
[code]

```
package com.coderzheaven.customfontinwidget;

import java.util.Timer;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static Timer myTimer;
    Intent myIntent;
    MyTimer obj_MyTime;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        System.out.println("onUpdate");
        startTimer(context);
    }

    void startTimer(Context context) {
        if (myTimer != null) {
            myTimer.cancel();
        }
        myTimer = new Timer();
        if (obj_MyTime == null)
            obj_MyTime = new MyTimer(context,
                    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context));
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(obj_MyTime, 1, 1000);
    }

    /*
     * This is called when an instance the App Widget is created for the first
     * time.
     */
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        startTimer(context);
        super.onEnabled(context);
    }

    /*
     * This is called for every broadcast and before each of the above callback
     * methods.
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    /* 
     * This is called When all instances of App Widget is deleted from the App
     * Widget host.
     */
    @Override 
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        System.out.println("All Widgets Deleted");
        // disposeWidget();
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }  

    /*
     * This is called every time an App Widget is deleted from the App Widget
     * host.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    public void disposeWidget() {
        if (myTimer != null) {
            myTimer.cancel();
            // myTimer.notifyAll();
            myTimer = null;
        }
        if (obj_MyTime != null) {
            obj_MyTime.cancel();
            // obj_MyTime.notifyAll();
            obj_MyTime = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[/code]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly - try instead of "Handler" use "TimerTask" which will be updating in some time (which you will set) example: [TimerTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477608/timer-and-timertask-in-android)

Comment: I am using TimerTask, can you see my class "MyTimer " is extending TimerTask.

Comment: Ok, but where you create this class? Could you get this code? Try instead of "mHandler.post(..." - new Handler().post(..

Comment: Can you please see my edit. Actullay the Log "Updating: is coming but the image is not updated.

Comment: Try in function "setBitmap" after setBitmap use on ImageView postInvalidate() of just invalidate(), maybe it will help

Comment: But this is a widget, how can I do that. can you please help me.

Comment: Here I think is what you need: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117133/android-change-widget-background-image)

Comment: There is nothing like postInvalidate() in that link