# my widget background disappears - android

Tags: android, android-widget

I've developed an android app, with a widget. The widget is working great except for one mobile device Samsung galaxy grand, android 4.1.2. The widget's background drawable disappears, while the text is still visible. I don't know if the problem is from the device, but I noticed that other widgets on this device don't have this problem. When I press and hold on the widget to remove it the background appears, then disappears again. I've tested the widget on other devices with the same API and its working well.

Any Suggestions about the reason?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dip"
android:background="@drawable/dthree"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetDateTV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/OLIVE" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetTextTV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/BROWN" 
    />
```

```
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                MyWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {



RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.widget_layout);

remoteViews.setInt(widgetId, "setBackground", R.drawable.dthree);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetTextTV, "some text");
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetDateTV,"date");


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DummyActivity.class);

            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,appWidgetIds);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetTextTV,
                    pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);}
```

Comment: How have you given the color, through xml or code ?

Comment: through xml.
android:background="@drawable/dthree"

Comment: Can you do it pragmatically and try it ?

Comment: I tried and still the same problem

Comment: ca you please share the code and xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by making ldpi, mdpi densties available. I was using one image in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so posting this as an answer instead, sorry for that.

I am not sure what the problem with Samsung galaxy grand is and why its not working specifically on that device and if its not working on one model then there is a good chance it doesn't work on others too. Try a little experiment just to try and work around the problem.

Try using `remoteViews.setImageViewResource()`.

Some others have solved this by using

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.viewid, "setBackgroundResource", R.color.somecolor);
```

Also, you could try and use a trick to use an ImageView for your background. Its explained here..

[Android Change Widget Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117133/android-change-widget-background-image)

Comment: thanks, but I solved this issue by changing the drawable's density.